# French footnotes with ConTeXt

Tags: footnotes, context

How to get french footnotes style :  number in baseline with dot in ConTeXt ?

1. my footnote

```tex
\mainlanguage[fr]
\setuppapersize[A4]



\starttext



This text requires an explanation \footnote{some text}.

\stoptext
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `\setupnotation` command to change the layout of the footnote block.

```
\mainlanguage[fr]

\setupnotation
  [footnote]
  [alternative=serried,
   numbercommand=,
   stopper=.]

\starttext
This text requires an explanation \footnote{some text}.
\stoptext
```

Comment: Thank you !  Sorry I have not seen you answer.

Answer (score 3):

Redefine `\footnotenumbercommand`

```
\mainlanguage[fr]
\setuppapersize[A4]

\define[1]\footnotenumbercommand{#1.}
\setupnotation [footnote] [numbercommand=\footnotenumbercommand, alternative=text]

\starttext
This text requires\footnote{Some text} an explanation \footnote{some other text}.
\stoptext
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! But why we can't get that automatically ?

Comment: I'd suggest you to make a request on context mailing-list: `ntg-context@ntg.nl`. This option might be then turned on by default when switching language